# How do I write a shell script to run a exe

Tags: shell, scripting

I have a exe file , how do I write a shell script to execute it. I am new to shell scripting . any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: On windows platform? Did you search Google? Also, please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Is this for Unix or Windows?

Comment: After searching google only I came here, hope everyone does the same

Comment: This is for Unix. I am trying in a Unix terminal

Comment: @Yogarajan exe's are Windows binaries, so do you have a way to run them or is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if I got you right, but shouln'd this be enough?

```
#!/bin/sh
clear 
echo "Running exe."
*path-to-.exe*/myexe.exe
exit 0
```

You can also thry this for a batch script

```
start /d *path-to-.exe*/myexe.exe
```

for future researchers, this was what op expected and found out by himself

```
userid="user" 
password="pass" 
servicename="svc" 
path/filename $userid $password $servicename
```

Comment: exe's are Windows binaries, so I think he means batch script rather than shell script.

Comment: @Yogarajan  was this a working solution for you? Or what do you mean by it?

Comment: the below code is what I expected. I found out myself...

userid="user"
password="pass"
servicename="svc"

path/filename $userid $password $servicename

Comment: yes what i mentioned here is working fine and that's what i wanted

Answer (score 0):

you have to just call the binary file from shell script e.g. below script file will execute a.out binary file

shell.sh contains and execute sh shell.sh
a.out

e.g. my shell.sh looks like 
[root@xyz]# cat shell.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
./a.out
```

If I execute shell.sh at command prompt using "sh shell.sh", I'll see o/p of a.out binary. I hope this helps.